# Qt Jambi Javadoc missing

Tags: java, eclipse, qt, maven, javadoc

When i fetched qt jambi jars from maven repository i found that there is no javadocs in it.
Downloading javadocs in maven didn't help.
My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
        <artifactId>qtjambi</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
            <artifactId>qtjambi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Specifies where sources are. This parameter is MANDATORY -->
                <sourcesDir>src/main/java</sourcesDir>
                <!-- following parameters aren't mandatory, they use defaults as specified 
                    here if not specified <translationsDir>src/main/resources/translations</translationsDir> 
                    <destinationDir>target/generated-sources/qtjambi</destinationDir> -->
                <!-- cause -noobsolete switch for lupdate -->
                <noObsoleteTranslations>true</noObsoleteTranslations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>qtjambi</id>
        <name>qtjambi</name>
        <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>qtjambi</id>
        <name>qtjambi</name>
        <url>http://qtjambi.sourceforge.net/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I've tried to download jar manually, but there is still no javadoc in it.

Comment: If you already checked that there are not JavaDoc than Maven is not able to download them either. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: it's very common gui library and it seems there must be javadoc on them,don't you think?
Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: See answer of Rober Scholte.

Answer (score 1):

http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-maven-plugin/4.6.3.1/ should contains `qtjambi-maven-plugin-4.6.3.1-javadoc.jar`. It's not there, so file a request at that project that they upload there javadocs as well.